# How can I delete my user account from the scifi stack? Also, how to meet the quality standards?

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-questions, question-quality

I am an active member of SO sites but I want to delete my account from this site, `scifi.stackexchange.com`. How can I do that?

I have tried to delete my questions from this site, but it's giving me errors like "this question has answers so you can't delete this question".

But I still want to delete not only my questions but also my account from this site. So how to do that?

---

And also, I am fed up with this error, "it does not meet our quality standards".

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete your account, change the “about me” field in your profile to `please delete me`. Then send an email to the e-mail listed under `contact us` at the bottom of every page on the site; be sure to include the URL to your profile (`http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/NNNNN` where NNNNN is your user ID) in the email. See [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account) on the main meta site for more information.

Your posts are a different matter: we do not want to delete valuable content. For example, if you have posted a question and it has an upvoted answer, you cannot delete it, because that would potentially delete a valuable answer as well. Whether you have deleted your account or not, your contributions will be submitted to the usual moderation process, so they will only be deleted if they are found unsuitable for the site. If you delete your account, your posts may remain, but they will not be associated with your name. See [If I delete my Stack Overflow account, will all my questions be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87709/if-i-delete-my-stack-overflow-account-will-all-my-questions-be-deleted) on the main meta site for more information.

The error “it does not meet our quality standards” comes from an automatic filter whose details are not public. See [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) on the main meta site for more information.

Comment: Will this delete his entire SO account or just his SciFi.SE.com account?

Comment: thanks @OghmaOsiris i was going to ask the same question.

Comment: @Vivart Accounts on different Stack Exchange sites are linked, but separate. Deleting your account here only affects [scifi.se] and [meta.scifi.se], not the rest of Stack Exchange. It might be more prudent to make it clear in your email that you only want the Scifi account deleted to avoid any mistake.

Comment: ok done i have sent mail.

Comment: @Gilles: I had an upvoted answer to one of this user's question, but the reputation change is not showing, is this because the question is under dispute by the user?  I'm just curious, don't worry about it if the answer is not to hand.

Comment: @iandotkelly [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/why-cobb-has-to-drug-fisher-in-the-air)? It currently has 0 votes. Maybe the asker upvoted it, then the vote vanished with the asker's account (when an account is deleted, the votes it cast disappear).

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, that answer.  That makes sense - thank you.